# Testing Android Apps with hardware component

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, android-espresso

I am looking for tools to help with testing my android app. It contains a hardware component and so far our only method is manual; obviously this isn't optimal.

The app uses the phones camera & a hardware attachment. Normally I would look into espresso for UI testing and Junit for unit tests but I don't want to start and get nowhere.

An answer here would suggest testing tools, and how they get around the hardware and camera constraints.

Answer (score 0):

How about calabash? ([GitHub](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android)) You can basically automate the touches you would make manually. We use it here to simulate barcodes being entered from a external usb scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on an android app that talks to custom hardware.  We ended up just mocking the interactions with the device for our espresso tests.